# proving that $\sup \limits_{x > 0} \frac{x\sin x}{x+1}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble proving that $$\sup ~ \Big\{  \frac{x\sin x}{x+1} \,:\, x>0 \Big\}=1$$ for my homework assignment. I have managed to prove that there is no $x$ so that $f(x) >1$ but cant seem to manage to prove there is no smaller number then $1$ for which that is true.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, when $x>0$ we have $|\frac{x}{x+1}\sin x| \leq |\sin x| \leq 1$, therefore we have the inequality $\frac{x}{x+1}\sin x \leq 1$.

Now, to prove that the supremum is indeed 1, we need to find a sequence $x_n$ such that the expression evaluated at $x_n$ tends to $1$. This can be done using the sequence defined in Austin Mohr's answer, but I think it is important to understand why that is the sequence you need. when you look at the expression $\frac{x}{x+1}\sin x$ you should notice that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x+1}=1$. The problem is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x$ does not exist. ( In fact, for every $\alpha \in [-1,1]$ there exists a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $\sin x_n \to \alpha$.)

Now, since $\sin $ is periodic, there exists a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $\sin x_n=1$, which is exactly the sequence chosen in the reffered answer.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_n\sin(x_n)}{x_n+1} &= \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n + 1}
\end{align*}
$$
which can be as close to $1$ as you please by taking $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: hmmmm.. Cool to formally probe this do I have to prove that the limit of that at x approaching infinity is 1?

Comment: @Jason Prove the limit of what is 1? If you mean my expression, then this is what I mean by "can be as close to 1 as you please by taking $n$ sufficiently large" (i.e. the limit of that expression as $n$ goes to infinity is 1). If you think your instructor wants to see the details, then you should include them. If you mean the original expression $\frac{x\sin x}{x+1}$, then no, because that limit is not equal to $1$ (and you wouldn't need it to be, anyway).

Comment: Yep I meant the limit of what expression. Thanks :) - BTW Just out of curiosity why is the limit of $xsinx/x+1$ not 1?

Comment: @Jason Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$. Plug it in and see that you can get as close as you like to $-1$, as well. Since we can get close to both $1$ and $-1$ infinitely often, the limit does not exist.